# Wordpress plugin WPS hide login multilingual

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on my website security so I've downloaded WPS hide login to hide the wp url to the users.
The fact is that my website is multilingual I'm using a translator plugin (Translatepress) (fr/en/es)
So when I do mydomain.com/login it's working but when I do mydomain.com/fr/ the login page didn't work anymore cause I can't edit multi login page

Let me show you the result of my research

The result with the /fr

[image]

The result without

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bonjour.

Your issue occure because the "WPS hide login" plugin is not compatible with multilingual plugins. Many people talk about this issue here : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-login-or-out-with-using-wp-hide-login-and-subdiretory-for-language/

The finaly solution is to use Defender, an alternative plugin with the same feature : https://wordpress.org/plugins/defender-security/